# How can i get the buyers to still be able to purchase the product even if its unavailable?

Tags: laravel, listener

I'm trying to create waitlist to buy product, but change the status of the transaction from 'Confirmed' to 'Waitlist'.

For that I have added a variable 'status' and a function in Transaction Model as follows:

```
const CONFIRMED_TRANSACTION = 'confirmed';
const WAITLIST_TRANSACTION = 'waitlist'; //waitlist product

public function isConfirmed() {
        return $this->status == Transaction::CONFIRMED_TRANSACTION;
    }
```

Default value of Transaction->status is 'CONFIRMED_TRANSACTION'.
Now every time the Product->status changes to 'unavailable' i would like to change the value of the Transaction->status to 'WAITLIST_TRANSACTION' when the transaction is created.

I am trying to achieve it using Event Listeners as:

```
Transaction::created(function($transaction) {
            if(!$product->isAvailable()) {
                $transaction->status = Transaction::WAITLIST_TRANSACTION;
                $transaction->save();
            }
        });
```

But this gives me error :

```
**ErrorException: Undefined variable: product in file /home/vagrant/restfulapi7/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php on line 29**
```

How can I achieve the same in a better way?

Comment: is there some kind of relation between Transaction & Product?

Comment: Maybe it should be `if(!$transaction->product->isAvailable())`

Comment: `if(!$transaction->product->isAvailable())` solves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the issue:

```
if(!$transaction->product->isAvailable())
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using what's called a lambda or anonymous function, which has a different scope to the rest of your code.

`function($transaction)` does not have access to a variable named `$product`. So you're trying to call `->isAvailable()` on a variable which doesn't exist.

```php
Transaction::created(function($transaction) {
            if(!$product->isAvailable()) {
                $transaction->status = Transaction::WAITLIST_TRANSACTION;
                $transaction->save();
            }
        });
```

Assuming it exists in the scope in which you call `Transaction::created()`, you can pass the `$product` variable into your lambda function like this:

`function($transaction) use ($product) { ... }`

For more information on lambda functions, read [the php docs here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)